# ORM api filter on many2one field

Tags: odoo

We can read and search data from Odoo using XML-RPC like it's explained on:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html

But, for "search" all the examples are using juste simple fields, there's no example to filter on relationship fields.

There is my case:

I have a partner(res.partner) who has a related user(res.user) on "user_id" field.

In this example, I try to get the ids of partners related to the user(id = 36)  on "user_id" field, but it doesn't work:

```
ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'search',
    [[['user_id', '=', 36]]],
    {'limit': 10})
```

Any ideas ?

Thank you,

Comment: A lot of possibilities can block your search, The Partners with user_id 36 can be inactive (field active set at false) or the search method of res.partner force specific domain... Have you any error message?

Comment: Thanks jo541 for you reply,

But I didn't get any message, just an empty array.
For infos, when I search partner and user by their ids, I get them,
I think there's no permission issue here

Comment: What happens if you search them in Odoo (Client)? How many does you find there? Try to debug into `models.Model.search()` to check the domain twice.

Comment: It's ok  CZoellner, 
Actually, I didn't execute this code:
ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
    'res.partner', 'search',
    [[['user_id', '=', 36]]],
    {'limit': 10})
But I executed the corresponding in PHP, and it was juste a problem of casting, the number 36 is a parameter and is considered as a string not a number.
That what is all about
Thanks for your replies you and jo541